# Removing category ID's from a selection list

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I have a plugin install called uCan post so registered users can post and what not, but I am wanting to have two category lists for them to choose from.

one is a country

the other is an activity list.

Now I have the two lists available but I want to exclude certain category ID's from one of the lists.

Here is the code for the category lists.

```
<!-- START EVENTS CATEGORIES -->
  <br />
  <?php
    if($this->ucan_options['uCan_Show_Categories'])
    {
  ?>

      <label>
        <?php echo __('Select Your Experience', 'ucan-post'); ?>:
      </label>
      <select name="ucan_submission_category">
        <?php
          foreach($categories as $category)
            if($category->cat_ID == $_POST['ucn_submission_category'])
              echo '<option value="'.$category->cat_ID.'" selected="selected">'.$category->name.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>';
            else
              echo '<option value="'.$category->cat_ID.'"">'.$category->name.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>';
        ?>
      </select>
  <?php
    }
  ?>
  <!-- END EVENTS CATEGORIES -->
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Where is `$categories` defined, and how is it defined?

Comment: Sorry I dont know too much about php, how would I find this out, I'm just looking in the plugin code right now.

Comment: Same file you pulled the above code from, just further up perhaps? You're looking for a line that starts with `$categories =` ..

Comment: There wasnt in that file but in another file it says
$categories = $this->uCan_Get_Categories();

Comment: Check the uCan plugin settings page(in your admin area), there's an exclude option for categories.

Comment: I do know that already :/ I have excluded some but I want my current categories left to kind of be split in two, so then I would exclude some from one then the others to the other one. If that makes any sense at all :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok then time to move my response into an answer, because it seems you just want to exclude categories from the loop in the above code..

Assuming you're alright to modify this file(a plugin update would overwrite it), then simply conditionalise your loop like so..

```
<?php
$excluded = array( 1, 2, 3 );
foreach($categories as $category)
    if( in_array( $category->cat_ID, $excluded ) )
        continue;
    else
        echo '<option value="'.$category->cat_ID.'"'. selected( $category->cat_ID, $_POST['ucn_submission_category'], false ).'>'.$category->name.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>';
?>
```

Untested, so let me know if any problems.

Replace 1,2 and 3 with the IDs of the categories you wish to exclude.

Comment: Ok I have done what you said and this has come up as a problem, here is the example = http://wordpress.art-williams.com/add-destination also, can you see what I am trying to do, by having the two category select bits. I appreciate all the help youve done so far

Comment: Ok I have now seen where I have placed it properly, and no it doesnt work. It doesnt exclude the category ID's

Comment: It should do... i've written loops like that more times than i can remember. Help me help you, what does "doesn't work" mean, can you expand on that?

Comment: I placed it were I should and it doesnt exclude the categories, I have changed the cat ID's and they still show

Comment: Yes, sorry i made a slight mistake in the code, try it now.

Comment: You're welcome ... though in future, please don't repost questions(it's a little insulting to people who take their time to respond). Happy i was able to help all the same.. ;)